# Exception: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: azure-webjobs

When i am deploying my WebJob to Azure i get the following error message:

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

The stacktrace doesn't help either see:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Queues\Listeners\QueueListener.cs:line 168
    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\TaskSeriesTimer.cs:line 147
    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnUnhandledExceptionAsync>b__0() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\WebJobsExceptionHandler.cs:line 54
    at System.Threading.Thread.ThreadMain_ThreadStart()
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Anybody have a general idea what could solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've recently run into the same problem.
Webjobs error out when their function can't correctly load their triggers.

As opposed to functions, Webjobs are really not quite talkative about what exactly went wrong when their bindings fail.

I'd check the following:

- Make sure you connection string is defined in your appsettings, Azure Config or Keyvault (or wherever you store your connection strings)
- Make sure the connection string is called "AzureWebJobsStorage" as the default Attributes (QueueTrigger) **only** look for that specific key in the config
- Make sure that the connection string is actually pointing to a storage that your webjob is allowed to access (for instance, don't point your dev subscription to your qa environment, that was my mistake)

Comment: You nailed it @Jejuni. In my case I forgot to set `AzureWebJobsStorage`. The exception is quite non descriptive. Thanks that helped a lot.